# Add Class to Header Nav for all Actions within a Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC website which has a standard navbar that displays text in the header that points to a certain controller and action. When I navigate to *localhost/* the *text-white bg-primary* classes are added to "Home". When I navigate to *localhost/Entry* the classes are added to "Entry".

However, when I navigate to anything other than those two directories (i.e. *localhost/Home/Index*, *localhost/Home/GetJobs*, *localhost/Entry/Review*) the classes are not added. My desired functionality is for the "Home" nav item to have the classes added to it for *localhost/Home/** as well as for "Entry" .. *localhost/Entry/**

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light header-box-shadow">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="appNavigation">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Entry">Manual Entry</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("nav a.nav-link[href='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("text-white bg-primary");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work for my use case. This would need some modification if your nav has links to multiple different actions under one controller.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");

    // shows current nav item for any page/action in the controller
    // e.g. /Home/Index, /Home/Search, etc. will change CSS of "Home" to show as the current nav item.
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        let element = elements[i];
        let href = element.attributes.getNamedItem("href").value.toString();

        // default page, "/" .. set href to default controller for proper matching
        if (href === "/") {
            // TODO: "get" default controller set by Endpoints Controller Route
            href = "/Home";
        }

        let path = location.pathname.split('/');
        path.pop();
        path = path.join('').toLowerCase();

        if (href.toLowerCase().includes(path)) {
            $(element).addClass("text-white bg-primary");

            // path is an empty string when at the default page "/" to avoid mismatches, stop the for loop from continuing
            if (path.length < 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```